# Page not found error in azure b2c custom policy with custom email verification

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, next-auth

I have integrated the custom policy with MFA authentication and it was working fine. I needed to send a custom verification email and changed the BASE and Extension Files according to the sample XML provided by Microsoft. now I have a custom email sent with a verification code to the user but as soon as the user fills out the forms azure AD user is made but I get a page not found error instead of a QR scan screen which I got before integrating the custom verification email. can someone help me with why is it happening?
[image]

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- This technical profile uses a validation technical profile to authenticate the user. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- This technical profile forces the user to verify the email address that they provide on the UI. Only after email is verified, the user account is
        read from the directory. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
          <DisplayName>Change password (username)</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: I would recommend setting up Application Insights tracing in the policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. This should allow you to get more info on the issue. The VS Code extension for AAD B2C can help you parse the traces that are produced. Sometimes errors show up in the Exceptions area of Application Insights as well.

Comment: i don't have access to setup application insights right now what else could it be like i am taking code from sample put up by microsoft yet both custom email and totp works fine when integrated seperately but when i integrate both it throws error on signup

Comment: i have setup application insights but logs are some json data which i don't think has any error mentioned in it can you help me with logs or some thing like application insights